# New and Returning visitor don't add up

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics

The sum of values of *New* and *Returning* Users is not equal to the header value displayed in the second column. The third column is correct though. Any thoughts on why this is happening in Google Analytics?

[image]

Comment: Not really a question for SO (webmasters is better suited), but the top numbers are unique visitors, while each visitor could fall under multiple buckets. For instance, if I came to your site at 6a, I'd fall under "new visitor".... then I came back at 5p, I'd fall under both the "new visitor" and "returning visitor" buckets... but I'm only 1 user.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know about webmaster stack exchange. Will post all the related questions over there from now on.

Comment: This covers it: https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/google-analytics-new-labels-mystery-of-the-returning-visitors